# How to inject script tag from template html in jasmine angularjs testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to inject a script tag which is in my template html for jasmine to use to run the test case. 
Lets say the html file is :

```
<script>
 <!-- imagine there is some cool javascript code in here - actual code not a link-->
</script>
<div>
    <h2>Imagine a question here?</h2>
    <input type="checkbox">Yes</input>
    <input type="checkbox">No</input>
</div>
```

the .js file is able to see the js within the script tag because the html is being loaded when the application is being run, but jasmine will not since it is not injected yet. is this possible ? Can html be called in the jasmine tests? 
I tried

```
$.getScript('link/to/html/page.html');
```

and

```
require('link/to/html/page.html');
```

but those didn't work (or throw any errors)

Comment: The `$.getScript` method loads and executes *JavaScript* files. Why are you loading an *HTML* file?

Comment: hi javascript can applied .But I think it is working after completely loaded of dom.so define that at the end of the file

Comment: @georgeawg I am trying to load the javascript which is in a script tag in the html file

Comment: @LDS at the end of the spec.ts file ?

Comment: The AngularJS framework does not support `<script>` elements in template files. JavaScript should be put in controllers and injected with the `ng-controller` directive.

Comment: @georgeawg do you mean it is bad practice or it doesn't work? Because I do have a script tag in my template and it loads successfully when the directive (loading the script tag) is called